# C++ set function parameter to null if nothing is passed like C#

Tags: c++, default-value

I'm trying to create a function in C++ which takes in 3 parameters, but the 3rd parameter I want to allow nothing to be passed.

Like for example
How can I code this C# function

```
public void GatherMovements( bool xPositions, bool yPositions, bool zPositions = null )
```

how can I create this in C++? is there a way?

Comment: `bool` can't be null in either C# or C++. You can *default* to true or false though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default arguments are possible. The problem here is that a `bool` cannot have a `null` value. So there are a few possibilities for you. You can either give that argument a default value that is a valid `bool`:

```
void GatherMovements(bool xPositions, bool yPositions, bool zPositions = false);
```

Or you can have two overloads of the function - one that takes 3 arguments and one that takes 2:

```
void GatherMovements(bool xPositions, bool yPositions, bool zPositions);
void GatherMovements(bool xPositions, bool yPositions);
```

One function may call the other if they can be implemented in terms of each other.

The second approach is only necessary if calling the function with `true`, `false`, and no final parameter are fundamentally different operations.

If you really want only one function and the three cases should be considered different, then one final option for you is to use a `boost::optional`:

```
void GatherMovements(bool xPositions, bool yPositions, boost::optional<bool> zPositions);
```

However, I suggest that the overload approach is preferable (no dealing with extra unnecessary types).

Comment: I know about overloads, Just wanted one method, do bool? exist in c++  :D cheers for the answer

Comment: @Canvas your example *does not* have a `bool?`. You might want to change that.

Answer (score 1):

Default parameters need to be listed in the declaration (not definition).
So, your declaration would be:

```
public:
 void GatherMovements(bool xPos, bool yPos, bool zPos = false);
```

and your definition would be:

```
void MyClass::GatherMovements(bool xPos, bool yPos, bool zPos /* = false */) {}
```

In addition, the default parameter needs to be passed by value here, i.e., you can't have:

```
public:
     void GatherMovements(bool xPos, bool yPos, bool& zPos = false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `boost` or the C++1y proposed `std::optional` you can solve this.

```
void GatherMovements(bool xPos, bool yPos, boost::optional<bool> zPos = boost::nullopt);
```

in the body of `GatherMovements`, you can tell if `zPos` was passed by doing `if(zPos)`.  You can get the `bool` value of `zPos` by doing `*zPos`.  In a sense, `zPos` follows C++ pointer semantics for dereferencing.

If you dereference `zPos` without checking to see if it is valid, you get undefined behavior.

It is easy to accidentally use `zPos` as a `bool` without dereferencing it by accident, so be careful.

Another option if you do not want to work with C++1y or `boost` would be to take a `bool const*`, and have an overload:

```
void GatherMovements_Internal(bool xPos, bool yPos, bool const* zPos);
void GatherMovements(bool xPos, bool yPos, bool zPos) { GatherMovements_Internal(xPos, yPos, &zPos); }
void GatherMovements(bool xPos, bool yPos) { GatherMovements_Internal(xPos, yPos, nullptr); }
```

now you write `GatherMovements_Internal`, and within it `zPos` is `nullptr` if it was not passed, and otherwise points to the `bool` that was passed.  Note that the lifetime of this pointer is not guaranteed to last past the function call (so do not store the pointer).

Use the same logic as the `optional` case above (`if (zPos)` to find out if it exists, and `*zPos` to get the value out if it exists).

Answer (score 0):

If using boost already / depending on it wouldn't be a problem, there's [tribool::indeterminate_value](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/tribool.html/) which you could use as a default value.